# Expand array of map type in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column with type **ArrayType(MapType(StringType, StringType))** and i want to expand in such way that keys present in map type becomes column name and its value(maptype) becomes value's of column.

here is an example:

[[version -> HTTP/1.1], [code -> 400], [reason -> Illegal character VCHAR='.'], [Content-Type -> text/html;charset=iso-8859-1], [Content-Length -> 70], [Connection -> close], [Server -> Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120)], [body -> 3c68313e426164204d65737361676520]]

this is a row which have arrayType() of maptype()

Comment: [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). How did you **get** this data? I suspect something wrong happened that created lists of one key-value each instead of just a single map

Comment: No, data is correct , so basically its a list of dict if i refer in python. There a single list in that list we have different different dictionaries.

Comment: I'm asking you to please show how you managed to get that ArrayType column. Otherwise, the answer is going to require you to write a UDF that iterates the list to build a dictionary, which you might as well use a function like that before you even get the data you've shown

Comment: So this a json which is i am fetch from kafka in string format  **{"http":[{"out":[{"version":"HTTP/1.1"},{"code":"400"},{"reason":"Illegal character VCHAR='.'"},{"Content-Type":"text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"},{"Content-Length":"70"},{"Connection":"close"},{"Server":"Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120)"},{"body":"3c68313e426164204d65737361676520"}]}]}** and then using struct type

Comment: Okay, so, why don't you work on editing the Kafka producer so it puts all the HTTP header information into a single map? Otherwise, why are you trying to get all consumers of the data need to "fix" the poor format?

Comment: yeah i can 't there is software which is producing this type of data and i can not config it.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the ArrayType. Use a UDF directly from the json

```
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType

@udf(returnType=MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
def http_flatten(s): 
    if s is None:
        return None
    import json 
    out = json.loads(s)["http"][0]["out"] 
    data = dict() 
    for e in out:
        data.update(e)
    return data
```

Then use something like this

```
kafka_df.select(
  http_flatten(
    kafka_df.value.cast("string").alias("value")
  ).alias("headers")
)
```

Then `select("headers.*")` to get those as the top level columns

Comment: okay thank you , but don't you think it will be a time taking approach ,means i am working on live environment and i have read somewhere that UDF is time taking.

Comment: Python UDFs can be slow, yes. But rewriting code in Scala might be even slower